# How to make gitlab to use a different user than git?

Tags: gitlab

I am trying to make gitlab to run with a different user and I wasn't able to find any place where it has this configured.

I tried this because I need to use a NIS account to running it and in fact I even removed the git local user, created one on NIS and tried to restart it like this (after fixing the ownerships due to the UID and GID changes).

```
STDERR: usermod: user 'git' does not exist in /etc/passwd
---- End output of ["usermod", "-g", "10032", "-s", "/bin/sh", "git"] ----
Ran ["usermod", "-g", "10032", "-s", "/bin/sh", "git"] returned 6
```

Full log: https://gist.github.com/ssbarnea/83b9c07678187dfe238f

It is perfectly normal for the git user not to be inside the passwd file, is a NIS user. Also, I wasn't able to find where does gitlab gets the 10032 value for the user group, why is trying to reconfigure it or how can I customise or bypass this.

Answer (score 2):

You would need first to [create/have a different user in place](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md#3-system-users).

And you would replace in the [installation documentation](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/install/installation.md) all instances of:

- `sudo -u git` with `sudo -u yourNewUser`
- user `git` with the right user, as in `/home/git/` replaced with `/home/yourNewUser/`

Check also the configuration file [`config/gitlab.yml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/1099468b320136c4c26816f281e956666a3b628e/config/gitlab.yml.example#L33-L34):

```
# Uncomment and customize if you can't use the default user to run GitLab (default: 'git')
# user: git
```

Comment: I installed gitlab using the installed, meaning that the config files from /etc/gitlab are not `gitlab.yml` files but some `gitlab.rb` which seems to be used to overwrite what is in `gitlab.yml` using a different syntax. I do not need to change the username anymore, just the group, hoping that I will not get the error above anymore. ... I don't want to loose the config when I will have to upgrade. Thanks!

Comment: @sorin ok. I would modify one or the other gitlab.yml file, putting an obvious 'false' value, in order to trigger an error (and see which one is actually used)

Comment: See my answer if you are using the GitLab Omni package.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bug report for this issue, relatively recent activity:
https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/737

The solution for me was to set the following in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb:

```
user['username'] = "git"
user['group'] = "git"
user['uid'] = 1040
user['gid'] = 1034
# # The shell for the git user
user['shell'] = "/bin/bash"
# # The home directory for the git user
user['home'] = "/var/home/git"
```

Adjust each value to match your existing NIS git user.

Then run gitlab-ctl reconfigure

To reiterate some comments on that bug report.  Basically setting those values above will cause gitlab to decide it doesn't need to create any users.